# Screen partial stream in Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that is like a whiteboard.

I'm able to mirror the screen through Chromecast, but this way the whole screen is streamed.

But I want that only a part of the screen be streamed, as I have the whiteboard itself and a toolbar that shouldn't be on the streaming.

Is it possible to choose what Views should be streamed on Android?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Streaming works via the video recording apps, it grabs the entire screen's data.  At that level it doesn't even know views exist.

Comment: your answer is incorrect so you might want to remove it to avoid confusion for users who read it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You should use the [Remote Display APIs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote) from Cast SDK v2 where you specify what view/surface in your app should be mirrored on a cast device. It is a great match for what you want to do.